# Are phone cameras interchangeable

Tags: components, interface

I was wondering what determines the availability of a phone to support a camera? and if lets say I have an 8MP camera from one phone manufacturer with the same number of pins that would connect to another phone from a different manufacturer would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These camera modules all use the same physical interfaces (MIPI) and I2C or similar.  But the register mappings are all different.  There is a standard register naming convention that is not strictly adhered to.  BUt you might have 100 or more registers inside.

TLDNR; No